# Multiparts and Multigeometries: checking for multigeometries with PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2

I have been working with **PyQGIS** and writing a small script to **check** whether the layers I have in the MapCanvas have **geometries of type "MultiXX"** because I want to run the "Multipart to Singleparts" processing algorithm on the layers that need to be processed (but not on the others because it would be too long). I need simple geometries because I am using the SPIT plugin to load them to a PostGIS database in a further step.

If I used this:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry()
        if geom.isMultipart():
          print (layer.name(), ": Warning: Multipart", feature.id())
...
```

I get whether every single feature is multipart or not. But I would like to determine the type of geometry on the layer itself, because I do not want to call the algorithm on the layer every time there is one feature multipart. So I tried this:

```
for layer in allLayers:
   if layer.wkbType() > '4':
      print "Warning Multigeometry in "+layer.name()
    ...
```

But somehow my layer, in which the multipart geometries would pop up with the first test, gets a wkbType of 3 (meaning Polygon).
So I am a bit confused: especially because QGIS tells me, the layer is a POLYGON layer, but the SPIT plugin tells me it is a MULTIPOLYGON layer (and indeed, there is a feature which is multipart and running the above mentionned processing algorithm resolve the problem).

Could someone explain to me how the relation between the geometry type and the multiparts aspect is working (I thought it was pretty simple: polygon => singleparts and multipolygons => multiparts) or suggest to me an alternative way to reach the same result, meaning:
checking accurately for layers with multigeometries in order to process them selectively.

Comment: Well, I have not clear out the theory part of my question, but for the implementation, I found an alternative:
I inserted a variable to count multiparts geometries in the first example, and at the end of the loop, if the variable is higher than 0, I call the function Multiparts to Singleparts.

Comment: if anyone ends up here in 2018, [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/234985/46528) answer might help you.