# How to select multi-part polygons from a layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, select, multipart

My script is -

```
# Find all multipart features in the active layer
l = iface.activeLayer()
iter = l.getFeatures()
geoms = []
for feature in iter:
    geom = feature.geometry()
    if geom.isMultipart():
        l.select(feature.id())
        geoms.append(geom)

print 'There are %i multipart features in this layer' % len(geoms)
```

I don't know the exact problem with this script.
Using this script in the Python console should select all multi part features in the active layer but in my case no multi section polygons fetched, while I can easily see multi section polygons exists in my polygon file.

Comment: Your title should be a summary of what is in the body of your question.  I think it would be worth you reviewing [this](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115) for some ideas on question structure.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, are you sure your layer is a multipolygon? You can check by typing `l.wkbType()`. If the value returned is `6` then it is a multipolygon. You can check [here for the wkb types](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsWkbTypes.html).

Comment: Joseph, thanks for the answer. I ran l.wkbType() it does'nt give '6' but I can clearly see that there are multi section polygons exist in my file.

Comment: @RakeshGiri - Try running `Vector > Geometry Tools > Singleparts to multipart` then try your code again. Also, if you want to notify someone, use the `@` before their name so that they can receive a notification. I just stumbled back to this post by coincidence :)

Comment: @Joseph thank you so much for your comment, It's working fine now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an easier alternative.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()   
layer.selectByExpression("num_geometries( $geometry ) > 1")
```

That's it!

---

After that, note that you could also know how many features are multi-part:

```
print('There are {} multipart features in this layer'.format(
    layer.selectedFeatureCount()))
```

Comment: @Carrillo thank you so much for your comments, Script is working fine now, and script shared by you also looks easy to work with.